# How to deploy env(dev, test, prod) specific Artifacts to Artifactory form Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, war, artifactory, artifacts

I am creating 3 Artifacts (war) for Dev, Test and Prod Environment using Profiles as following:

```
clean install -P dev
cp target/ABC.war output/ABC-dev-${BUILD_NUMBER}.war

clean install -P test
cp target/ABC.war output/ABC-test-${BUILD_NUMBER}.war

clean install -P prod
cp target/ABC.war output/ABC-prod-${BUILD_NUMBER}.war
```

To execute this from Jenkins I am using Jenkins plugin "Invoke top-level Maven targets".

Once created all war's, I wants to deploy these to Artifactory!

I google a lot but didn't find anything regarding just deploy my artifacts to Artifactory.

> Note: I am able to build and deploy my artifact with "clean deploy -P
>   dev", but in that case I am not able to modify my artifact name.
>   (Companies Artifactory doesn't allow to deploy without versioning
>   enabled)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) in order to publish different files to different locations base on a pattern. For example:

```
jfrog rt u "*dev*" "dev-repo/path/to/file"
jfrog rt u "*test*" "test-repo/path/to/file"
```

That was you don't have to know the exact file name and can use the pattern for uploading the files to the right location.

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cURL` to upload your `war` files to Artifactory.

```
$ curl -v --user username:password --data-binary @/local/path/to/war-file/ABC-dev.war -X PUT "http://org.artifactory.com/artifactory/repo_name/folder_name/ABC-dev-${BUILD_NUMBER}.war
```

"

Comment: I tried curl, but in this case I am only uploading a war file and not other files (war.md5 , war.sha1, pom, pom.md5, pom.sha1)!

Also, I used version number form Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER in my pom.xml and used "clean deploy -P dev", it upload everything (war, war.md5 , war.sha1, pom, pom.md5, pom.sha1) but pom.xml will still have variable ${BUILD_NUMBER} instead of value.

Comment: Also war is uploading but it seems corrupted with above curl, it's just 41 bytes!